# Android Cipher encrypt/decrypt

Tags: android, encryption

I'm using cipher to encrypt and decrypt messages:

```
public String encrypt(String string) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
  byte[] stringBytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
  byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringBytes);
  return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public String decrypt(String string) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
  byte[] stringBytes = android.util.Base64.decode(string.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
  byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringBytes);
  return new String(decryptedBytes,"UTF-8");
}
```

For some reason although I'm using Base64 to encode and decode the string, I still get this error:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

This is my JSONObject - I'm trying to decrypt the "m":

```
{"m":"Cu7FR2be0E6ZP2BrZaLU2ZWQSfycNg0-fPibphTIZno\r\n"}
```

The weird thing is that the error only appears in Android. My server is written in Java and I'm using Apache Base64 encoder and it works great.

Comment: decrypt ("\u0000") or some unicode char will always nag of that

Comment: the weird thing is that the error only appears in Android.. my server is written in java and i'm using apache Base64 encoder and it works great...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert Base-64 first.

CODEED = encrypt(Base64.encode(MYSTRING, Base64.DEFAULT));

MYSTRING = Base64.decode(decrypt(CODEED), Base64.DEFAULT);

here is a link http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html

Comment: i now get java.io.IOException: Bad Base64 input character decimal 45 in array position 31 - in the Base decoding

Comment: the weird thing is that the error only appears in Android.. my server is written in java and i'm using apache Base64 encoder and it works great...

Comment: http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings I checked this class and also made a test android app, tested your object, code and decode worked fine!

Comment: could it be that its a bit slow ? i've tried to use it and the ToHex method make it a bit slow..

Comment: are you doing a mass operation? how long It makes you wait?

Comment: not long, but longer then the BASE64... i've read about it and the Base64 is more efficient.. but if i want find a solution for it - i will this code.. thanks !

Comment: you were right and the problem was that Android Base64 encoding and the Apache Base64 wasn't the same. i've used your class in the client and in the server and it works like a charm...

Comment: I am glad that I could help

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems OK to me, you can try to add "UTF-8" before decoding.

```
byte[] stringBytes = android.util.Base64.decode(string.getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**EDIT**

This is an example Security Utility class which do encryption/decryption that uses BouncyCastle and password-based AES encryption.

```
public class SecurityUtils {

public static final String KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";

private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

private static final String DELIMITER = "]";

private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;

private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 1000;

private static final int SALT_LENGTH = 8;

private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

static {
    Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}


public static String encrypt(Context context, String plaintext)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] salt = generateSalt();
    return encrypt(plaintext, getKey(salt, getPassword(context)), salt);
}

private static String encrypt(String plaintext, SecretKey key, byte[] salt)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, "BC");

        byte[] iv = generateIv(cipher.getBlockSize());
        IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        if (salt != null) {
            return String.format("%s%s%s%s%s",
                    new String(Base64.encode(salt)), DELIMITER, new String(
                            Base64.encode(iv)), DELIMITER, new String(
                            Base64.encode(cipherText)));
        }

        return String.format("%s%s%s", new String(Base64.encode(iv)),
                DELIMITER, new String(Base64.encode(cipherText)));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new Exception("Error while encryption", e);
    }
}

public static String decrypt(Context context, String ciphertext)
        throws Exception {
    return decrypt(ciphertext, getPassword(context));
}

private static String decrypt(String ciphertext, String password)
        throws Exception {
    String[] fields = ciphertext.split(DELIMITER);
    if (fields.length != 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid encypted text format");
    }
    try {
        byte[] salt = Base64.decode(fields[0]);
        byte[] iv = Base64.decode(fields[1]);
        byte[] cipherBytes = Base64.decode(fields[2]);

        SecretKey key = getKey(salt, password);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, "BC");
        IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
        byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
        String plainrStr = new String(plaintext, "UTF-8");

        return plainrStr;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new Exception("Error while decryption", e);
    }
}

private static String getPassword(Context context) {

    return "My secret password";
}

private static SecretKey getKey(byte[] salt, String password)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt,
                ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(
                KEY_DERIVATION_ALGORITHM, "BC");
        byte[] keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new Exception("Error while generating key", e);
    }
}

private static byte[] generateIv(int length) {
    byte[] b = new byte[length];
    random.nextBytes(b);

    return b;
}

private static byte[] generateSalt() {
    byte[] b = new byte[SALT_LENGTH];
    random.nextBytes(b);

    return b;
}
```

}

Comment: You can try this class, just tweak it to your needs and add BouncyCastle jars to your project.

Comment: does this work properly considering http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html ?