# encryption an decryption of a text

Tags: android

Is it possible to encrypt and decrypt a text in android but i found a error but i dont know how to fix it,

The code is...

```
   Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());        
    byte[] input = " www.java2s.com ".getBytes();
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
        0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17 };

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding", "BC");
    System.out.println("input text : " + new String(input));

    // encryption pass

    byte[] cipherText = new byte[input.length];
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
    ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
    System.out.println("cipher text: " + new String(cipherText) + " bytes: " + ctLength);

    // decryption pass

    byte[] plainText = new byte[ctLength];
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    int ptLength = cipher.update(cipherText, 0, ctLength, plainText, 0);
    ptLength += cipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);
    System.out.println("plain text : " + new String(plainText) + " bytes: " + ptLength);
```

The firstline showing the error

Comment: have a look at this http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

Answer (score 0):

You should first be aware that encryption become very vulnerable when you fix the key or generate a non-secure one!

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022934/android-cipher-encrypt-decrypt/14023167#14023167) you will find a generic easy to use SecurityUtil class that do secure password-based AES encryption/decryption which might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error comes from the first line you probably forgot to [add the bouncycastle provider](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation).